# Database Queue Connection not working in production

Tags: laravel, cron, laravel-queue

My Laravel (7.15) application with `cron-job` contains two commands which executes daily at certain time period.

```
php artisan report:generate
php artisan report:send-mail
```

`report:generate` command executes once while `report:send-mail` executes in every 5 mins.

Until yesterday in production `QUEUE_CONNECTION` was `sync` and it was working perfectly. But the problem is my reports contain large & complex queries which take approx 2-3 hours for each (tables have millions of data too).

So I decided to move my reports into `queued-jobs` which can be generated parallelly. And so I changed my `QUEUE_CONNECTION` to `database`. And run the following commands in production.

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan queue:flush
php artisan queue:retart
```

`queue:work` is already running on my server & unfortunately I don't have access to that to turn it off and on (network team authorized only).

I already ran `queue:table` & `queue:failed-table` before which generated `jobs` & `failed_jobs` table in production database.

Now I got job entries for each report but its not attempting, `attempts` is showing `0` in `jobs` table. It seems queue is not working for generating report while it is working for sending report mail. For test, I tried `queue:work` manually by command & generated a single mail successfully in production.

What's going on & how can I solve this issue?

Comment: did you use supervisord?

Comment: @HamidShariati yes

Answer (score 0):

as you commented that used supervisord, restart supervisord.